# Bootstrap tooltip on method => :delete link in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using `method: :delete` on a link in rails, and trying to get a bootstrap tooltip on it.

This doesn't show a tooltip:

```
=link_to "destroy", blog_path(blog), "data-original-title" => "Delete your answer", "data-placement" => "top", :rel => "tooltip", method: :delete
```

However, if I remove the `method: :delete`, the tooltip works.

How can I get a tooltip on a delete link?

Comment: have you added the tooltip handler to your anchors - e.g. `$('a[rel="tooltip"]').tooltip()`?

Comment: Yep, added it. The tooltip works fine if I remove the `method: :delete`, so I think it has to do with that addition.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had the same problem and didn't find any suitable solution so I started tinkering with it myself.

If you remove the `:rel => "tooltip"` and add anything else, for example `:rel => "nofollow"`, and then call `$('a[rel="nofollow"]').tooltip()` manually it works.

Here's the final result:

```
<%= link_to "destroy", blog_path(blog), "data-original-title" => "Delete your answer", "data-placement" => "top", :rel => "nofollow", method: :delete %>
```

And also add the code to show the tooltip after this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function() {
    $('a[rel="nofollow"]').tooltip();
  });
</script>
```

**EDIT**: this is not a issue anymore.

Answer (score 18):

This is a JQuery selector problem.

If you use something like:

```
$('a[rel="tooltip"]').tooltip();
```

You're telling the JQuery selector to take the only the elements with rel attribute with only **"tooltip"** value.

So I believe what you're looking for is this piece of code.

```
$('a[rel~="tooltip"]').tooltip();
```

So, now JQuery will take all the elements that has the **"tooltip"** word inside the **rel** attribute.

More information below.

http://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-word-selector/

Comment: FYI, using `$('a[rel*="tooltip"]')` is similar but finds a **substring** instead of a **whole word** so the `~=` used above in @guivinicius' answer is preferred. Carry on! :)

Comment: This should absolutely be the correct answer, I had completely forgotten anything like this existed, thanks guiv!!